# Phalcon rendering half the page/rendering weirdly

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

[image: What the page looks like]

^What my page looks like.

For some reason I get this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getHash() on null in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/views/index/index.volt.php:146\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: unknown()\n#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt->render('../application/...', Array, true)\n#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View->_engineRender(Array, 'index/index', true, true, NULL)\n#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\View->render('index', 'index', Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/coinpot/public/index.php(158): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/views/index/index.volt.php on line 146

when loading my page.

I also get a slew of others errors.

```
[Sat Oct 08 09:35:39.137966 2016] [:error] [pid 24670] [client ] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/controllers/BaseController.php on line 37
[Sat Oct 08 09:35:39.143992 2016] [:error] [pid 24670] [client ] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: pool in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/views/index/index.volt.php on line 101
[Sat Oct 08 09:35:39.144012 2016] [:error] [pid 24670] [client ] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/views/index/index.volt.php on line 101
[Sat Oct 08 09:35:39.144037 2016] [:error] [pid 24670] [client ] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: deposits in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/views/index/index.volt.php on line 134
[Sat Oct 08 09:35:39.144050 2016] [:error] [pid 24670] [client ] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/views/index/index.volt.php on line 134
[Sat Oct 08 09:35:39.144070 2016] [:error] [pid 24670] [client ] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: pool in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/views/index/index.volt.php on line 146
```

Lines 136-152 index.volt.php

```
    function decimalPlaces(float,length) {
        ret = "";
        str = float.toString();
        array = str.split(".");
        if(array.length==2) {
            ret += array[0] + ".";
            for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
                if(i>=array[1].length) ret += '0';
                else ret+= array[1][i];
            }
        } LINE 146
        else if(array.length == 1) {
            ret += array[0] + ".";
            for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
                ret += '0'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you show the code flow mentioned in the error messages?

Comment: Added line 146 error

Answer (score 0):

I can't see index.volt.php so my guess is this.

Add  `= NULL` to the index.volt.php line 146 after the variable or variables for the getHash function in the () brackets.

Also the notices show in localhost but not online. You can add `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` or change it in php.ini to get rid of the notices. You don't have to fix notices.

Comment: did a command+f in index.volt.php, getHash is never called. Its defined in my model Pool.  `public function getHash()
 {
  return md5($this->getPercentage() . $this->secret);
 }`

Comment: Change it to `if (isset($this->getPercentage()) && isset($this->secret)) { public function getHash())){ return md5($this->getPercentage() . $this->secret); }}`

Comment: Tried, new error and HTTP error 500. `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /var/www/html/coinpot/application/models/Pool.php on line 97`

Comment: I think I have the answer. Both `$this->getPercentage()` and `$this->secret()` are blank.